# Excel multiple arguments for AND function

Tags: excel

I need to check multiple cells and return TRUE if the value in all the cells is a number. 
Example:

```
A2,A4, A5,A8,A12,A16 <p>
```

Currently I am writing the formula as below:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(A2),ISNUMBER(A4),ISNUMBER(A5),ISNUMBER(A8),ISNUMBER(A12),ISNUMBER(A16)),"All Numbers","Some not numbers")
```

Is there someway to write the formula with only one `ISNUMBER` function to which an array of cells are passed?

Comment: NO. No such worksheet function is prepared in excel. But, you can create such function by VBA program (macro).

Comment: Thanks Fumu. We need to send the Worksheet to not-so-tech-savvy people scatterred at different locations and would prefer a macro-less solution because of the support dependencies in case of macros

Comment: Would it matter if I counted a blank cell as a number? If that's ok (i.e. you control the input range so not to include a blank cell) then there is a solution although you'd have to pass the range in twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the numbers will only ever be non-zero and positive:

```
=IF(INDEX(FREQUENCY((A2,A4,A5,A8,A12,A16),0),2)=COUNTA(A2,A4,A5,A8,A12,A16),"All Numbers","Some not numbers")
```

Otherwise:

```
=IF(SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"A2","A4","A5","A8","A12","A16"}),{">=0";"<0"}))=COUNTA(INDIRECT({"A2","A4","A5","A8","A12","A16"})),"All Numbers","Some not numbers")
```

If the range of cells over which you are performing this check is fixed, and not dynamic, then we can shorten these to:

```
=IF(INDEX(FREQUENCY((A2,A4,A5,A8,A12,A16),0),2)=6,"All Numbers","Some not numbers")
```

or:

```
=IF(SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"A2","A4","A5","A8","A12","A16"}),{">=0";"<0"}))=6,"All Numbers","Some not numbers")
```

Regards

Comment: Thanks XOR LX. This works exactly as I wanted. The requirement has changed a bit and I am sure you will be able to help me. Now instead of checking whether the cells have numbers, the requirement is that cells in question are not blank(clarification: the range is fixed), then what formula do I use? "Blank" means has some value (alpha/numeric etc other than the space character). Thanks in advance.

Comment: To clarify further, the formula should return TRUE only if all the cells have a value (i.e NOT blank) and should return a FALSE if even one cell has a blank.

Comment: Ok. Change to: =SUM(COUNTIF(INDIRECT({"A2","A4","A5","A8","A12","A16"}),{"?*";">0"}))=6

Answer (score 1):

If the cells you want to check are in a contiguous array you can use an array formula with the `isnumber` function:

`=ISNUMBER(A2:A5)` and then press `ctrl+shift+enter` instead of just `enter`. When you then look at the cell the formula should be enclosed by curly braces like `{=ISNUMBER(A2:A5)}`

If the cells are not in a contiguous array this will not work, however

Comment: Thanks Zrethreal, The range is not contiguous

Answer (score 0):

well, to be frank.. since you want them to input number on those cells, why don't you just use data validation? (can be found on DATA tab > Data Validation). Choose decimal and you can even set the range of minimum to maximum value. I personally think that this is a sounder solution to your case, since the users will not be able to enter values besides number.

Answer (score 0):

`COUNT` function only counts numbers (not text or error values or logical values or blanks), so this formula will give the same result as your current formula with multiple `ISNUMBER` functions

`=IF(COUNT(A2,A4,A5,A8,A12,A16)=6,"All Numbers","Some not numbers")`